# PHP and SQL Shopping Cart is Not Adding Products to Shopping Cart

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, session, shopping-cart

I am trying to make a simple MSSQL and PHP shopping cart for my website. The page `index.php` correctly retrieves the products from my MSSQL `products` table and displays them. For each product displayed there is an `Add to Cart` button. The button should use `$_SESSION` to store the added product into the shopping cart via the `cart_update.php` page. The products added to the shopping cart should be displayed at the bottom of the index.php page. Currently, when the `Add to Cart` button is hit, no products are added to the shopping cart. I am unsure why this is happening.

Here is my `index.php` page code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="products">
<?php
//current URL of the Page. cart_update.php redirects back to this URL
$current_url = base64_encode("http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id ASC";
    $results = mssql_query($query, $mysqli);
    if ($results) { 
        //output results from database
        while($obj = mssql_fetch_object($results))
        {

            echo '<div class="product">'; 
            echo '<form method="post" action="cart_update.php">';
            echo '<div class="product-thumb"><img src="images/'.$obj->product_img_name.'"></div>';
            echo '<div class="product-content"><h3>'.$obj->product_name.'</h3>';
            echo '<div class="product-desc">'.$obj->product_desc.'</div>';
            echo '<div class="product-info">Price '.$currency.$obj->price.' <button class="add_to_cart">Add To Cart</button></div>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="'.$obj->product_code.'" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="'.$current_url.'" />';
            echo '</form>';
            echo '</div>';
        }

}
?>
</div>
<div class="shopping-cart">
<h2>Your Shopping Cart</h2>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["products"]))
{
    $total = 0;
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm)
    {
        echo '<li class="cart-itm">';
        echo '<span class="remove-itm"><a href="cart_update.php?removep='.$cart_itm["code"].'&return_url='.$current_url.'">&times;</a></span>';
        echo '<h3>'.$cart_itm["name"].'</h3>';
        echo '<div class="p-code">P code : '.$cart_itm["code"].'</div>';
        echo '<div class="p-qty">Qty : '.$cart_itm["qty"].'</div>';
        echo '<div class="p-price">Price :'.$currency.$cart_itm["price"].'</div>';
        echo '</li>';
        $subtotal = ($cart_itm["price"]*$cart_itm["qty"]);
        $total = ($total + $subtotal);
    }
    echo '</ol>';
    echo '<span class="check-out-txt"><strong>Total : '.$currency.$total.'</strong> <a href="view_cart.php">Check-out!</a></span>';
    echo '<span class="empty-cart"><a href="cart_update.php?emptycart=1&return_url='.$current_url.'">Empty Cart</a></span>';
}else{
    echo 'Your Cart is empty';
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my `cart_update.php` page code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
session_start(); //start session
include_once("config.php"); //include config file

//empty cart by distroying current session
if(isset($_GET["emptycart"]) && $_GET["emptycart"]==1)
{
    $return_url = base64_decode($_GET["return_url"]); //return url
    session_destroy();
    header('Location:'.$return_url);
}

//add item in shopping cart
if(isset($_POST["type"]) && $_POST["type"]=='add')
{
    $product_code   = filter_var($_POST["product_code"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //product code
    $product_qty    = filter_var($_POST["product_qty"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); //product code
    $return_url     = base64_decode($_POST["return_url"]); //return url

    //limit quantity for single product
    if($product_qty > 10){
        die('<div align="center">This demo does not allowed more than 10 quantity!<br /><a href="http://sanwebe.com/assets/paypal-shopping-cart-integration/">Back To Products</a>.</div>');
    }
    $query = "SELECT product_name,price FROM products WHERE product_code='$product_code' LIMIT 1";
    //MySqli query - get details of item from db using product code
    $results = mssql_query($query, $mysqli);
    $obj = mssql_fetch_object($results);

    if ($results) { //we have the product info 

        //prepare array for the session variable
        $new_product = array(array('name'=>$obj->product_name, 'code'=>$product_code, 'qty'=>$product_qty, 'price'=>$obj->price));

        if(isset($_SESSION["products"])) //if we have the session
        {
            $found = false; //set found item to false

            foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) //loop through session array
            {
                if($cart_itm["code"] == $product_code){ //the item exist in array

                    $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'code'=>$cart_itm["code"], 'qty'=>$product_qty, 'price'=>$cart_itm["price"]);
                    $found = true;
                }else{
                    //item doesn't exist in the list, just retrive old info and prepare array for session var
                    $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'code'=>$cart_itm["code"], 'qty'=>$cart_itm["qty"], 'price'=>$cart_itm["price"]);
                }
            }

            if($found == false) //we didn't find item in array
            {
                //add new user item in array
                $_SESSION["products"] = array_merge($product, $new_product);
            }else{
                //found user item in array list, and increased the quantity
                $_SESSION["products"] = $product;
            }

        }else{
            //create a new session var if does not exist
            $_SESSION["products"] = $new_product;
        }

    }

    //redirect back to original page
    header('Location:'.$return_url);
}

//remove item from shopping cart
if(isset($_GET["removep"]) && isset($_GET["return_url"]) && isset($_SESSION["products"]))
{
    $product_code   = $_GET["removep"]; //get the product code to remove
    $return_url     = base64_decode($_GET["return_url"]); //get return url


    foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) //loop through session array var
    {
        if($cart_itm["code"]!=$product_code){ //item does,t exist in the list
            $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'code'=>$cart_itm["code"], 'qty'=>$cart_itm["qty"], 'price'=>$cart_itm["price"]);
        }

        //create a new product list for cart
        $_SESSION["products"] = $product;
    }

    //redirect back to original page
    header('Location:'.$return_url);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for any help. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would add some debug code to your `cart_update.php` code to see if you are getting the info correctly. Like after `$obj = mssql_fetch_object($results);` add `print_r($obj); die();` and see what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add products to the shopping cart I had to change the query in the `cart_update.php` page where

```
$query = "SELECT product_name,price FROM products WHERE product_code='$product_code LIMIT 1'";
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT TOP 1 product_name,price FROM products WHERE product_code='$product_code'";
```

This is because `LIMIT` does not work in SQL Server, and the equivalent is `TOP`.